# AppleScript cannot save a textedit file

Tags: applescript

I'm using a code to format textedit files for lab data.

I currently am using AppleScript to create a document in TextEdit and adding text to it, but when I try to save it, TextEdit gives me the error "you do not have permission to save as blahblahblah." I have already tried changing the permission on the folder in which I'm saving it in, but I think it may have something to do with it being a file that AppleScript created.

The exact error output is a dialog box from TextEdit

> The document “1.txt” could not be saved as “1”. You don’t have permission.
>
> To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

The segments of my code that don't work are

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    make new document with properties {name:("1.txt")}
end tell


--data formatting code here (n is set here)


tell application "TextEdit"
    delay 1
        
    close document 1 saving in ("/Users/bo/Desktop/Script Doc/" & (n as string))
    
    set n to n + 1
    make new document with properties {name:((n as string) & ".txt")}
    delay 1
end tell
```

I have scoured other questions and I have found the code segments

```
open for access document 1
close access document 1
```

but I'm not sure how to implement these / if I even should, and if not, I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving directly to the Desktop works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave

```
property outputPath : POSIX path of (((path to desktop as text) & "Script Doc") as alias)
property docNumber : 1
property docExtension : ".txt"

tell application "TextEdit"
    set docName to (docNumber & docExtension) as text
    set theText to "Your Desired Text Content"

    set thisDoc to make new document with properties {name:docName, text:theText}
    close thisDoc saving in POSIX file (outputPath & "/" & (name of thisDoc))

    (* IF YOU WANT TO SAVE MULTIPLE FILES WITH CONSECUTIVE NAMES *)
    set docNumber to docNumber + 1
    set docName to (docNumber & docExtension) as text

    set thisDoc2 to make new document with properties {name:docName} -- Removed Text Property This Time
    close thisDoc2 saving in POSIX file (outputPath & "/" & (name of thisDoc2))
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that error message isn't helping much.  You are essentially trying to save into a string, which isn't going to work - you need to use a **file specifier**, for example:

```
close document 1 saving in POSIX file ("/Users/bo/Desktop/Script Doc/" & n & ".txt")
```

Note that not everything knows about POSIX paths, in which case you will need to coerce or specify it as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

TextEdit is sandboxed. You cannot save documents in the standard desktop folder.

An alternative is to hard-code the path to the documents folder in the container of TextEdit.

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    make new document with properties {name:"1.txt"}
end tell


set containerDocumentsFolder to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Containers:com.apple.TextEdit:Data:Documents:"
tell application "TextEdit"

    close document 1 saving in containerDocumentsFolder & (n as string) & ".txt"

    set n to n + 1
    make new document with properties {name:(n as string) & ".txt"}
end tell
```